# computer controlled thermostat

Tags: home-automation

I would like to find an easy way to control a thermostat via a microcontroller or computer.

Ideally, it would be a normal looking thermostat with digital display that could be controlled via RS-232 or other connection.

(Hoping to hook it up to an RPI or otherwise)

Are there any thermostats like this that aren't going to break the bank?
Or does anyone have any other advice?

Comment: Range of temperature? You need to explain more about what you are trying to do, and what you have already attempted. Why do you need to purchase the thermostat? A thermostat is just a temp sensor and a switch, and can be implemented with just a few cheap components. A PIC16F, with LCD, relay and something like an DS18B20/thermistor/thermocouple sounds like it would probably do what you are asking.

Comment: Try to define a question like a spec; Budget = ?, Features =? reliability=? interface =?  Thermostats are cheap now. If you turn off your own wall mount, you can wire in parallel with contacts with any external isolated switch and use multiple thermistors around the house such as TMP series chip (cheap ) 24Vac contacts are used

Comment: http://www.nest.com/ Without specified budget constraints or feature requirements, the default answer is a pre-made solution

Answer (score 1):

Piece of cake. Since you'll have the EIA232 interface for remote programming I'll keep the user interface for the thermostat itself simple. Microcontroller shopping list:

- UART
- I2C and/or SPI
- 2k or 4k Flash
- around 16 digital I/O, able of 20 mA drive

High speed isn't required; 1 MHz or so is enough. Plenty of microcontrollers will fit this picture, like for instance the AVR [ATtiny48](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8008.pdf) to name one. Available in a DIL package, may be a plus.

This is what the **display** could look like:

[image]

You probably don't need 4 digits, for 3 digits you need 11 I/Os.

For the **temperature sensor** you could use one with digital interface, SPI or I2C, or analog; the ATtiny48 has ADC. I2C needs 2 wires, versus 4 for SPI, and I2C has the advantage that it's a bus, where you can connect more than 1 sensor if required. The [TCN75A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21935D.pdf) also mentioned by *dadinck* is suitable: a 2°C accuracy, and you can connect 8 of them to your bus.
That's 2 I/O pins.

The **UART** will only need TX and RX, that's 2 pins, which interface to a MAX3232 or similar transceiver.

The **RTC** can be an I2C device, so we hook that up on the bus. Let's use a [PCF8563](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF8563.pdf) for that.

The ATtiny48 only has 64 bytes of **EEPROM** on board, and that may or may not be enough to store the thermostat program. You'll need 3 bytes per switching moment: 11 bits for time of day (9 bits if a 5 minute resolution is enough), 7 bits for days of the week, and 5 or so to store the temperature for that time. With the internal EEPROM you can store 21 switching moments, but then there's only 1 byte left for other settings (whatever they might be). Anyway, if you need more EEPROM, again  we'll use an I2C device, like the [AT24C04B](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc5226.pdf). 512 bytes and only 28 cent.

We've used 15 I/Os so far, and we'll obviously need one to switch the heating through a **relay**. That's 16. The ATtiny48 in DIL has 23 I/Os available, so there are a few left for **buttons/switches**. You'll want at least a on-program-off switch.

The ATtiny48 has an **internal oscillator** which can be calibrated to 1 % accuracy. (Personally I would have preferred that Atmel did this in production.)

The **4 kB Flash** should leave you enough spare memory to include a flight simulator, so to speak.

That's a basic setup with an AVR. You can do the same with a PIC or any other 8-bit controller for a comparable price.

The **power supply** can be a compact module like [this one](http://www.myrrel.com/images/47000%20series%20Electronic%20Transformers.pdf):

[image: PS]

More compact and efficient that the classic linear regulator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a serial out temperature sensor [TCN75](http://www.microchipdirect.com/ProductDetails.aspx?Catalog=BuyMicrochip&Category=TCN75A&mid=14&treeid=2) and a [PIC24](http://www.microchipdirect.com/ProductDetails.aspx?Catalog=BuyMicrochip&Category=PIC24FJ16GA002&mid=14&treeid=8) which has a UART. There should be lots of digital fun with these chips and in a quantity of 1, they are US $.70 and $2.58 respectively.